# SQL SERVER using a variable that contains a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a table as a variable but it gives me an error.

```
   DECLARE @tbl_var as varchar(50)
   SET @tbl_var = 'Table_Sales'
   SELECT * FROM @tbl_var
```

I understand that I need to declare the variable @tbl_var as a table, but even when I do it gives me an error

```
    DECLARE @tbl_var as table
   SET @tbl_var = 'Table_Sales'
   SELECT * FROM @tbl_var
```

Also, it's not possible for me to declare all the columns because it has a hundred columns.

```
   DECLARE @tbl_var as table ( A as varchar(10), B as varchar(10)....)
       SET @tbl_var = 'Table_Sales'
       SELECT * FROM @tbl_var
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need dynamic SQL.

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.

Comment: You mean *parameter* not variable. Table names can't be parameters. Tables in SQL are like types in a strongly typed language like C#, C++ or Java. They can't be passed as parameters by name. The server doesn't execute a query directly, it creates an execution plan based on the tables, column types, indexes, constraints *and* data statistics. It can't do that when it doesn't even know what the table is. The *same* query can result in very different execution plans when applied to different tables

Comment: That's not how you declare a table variable. `DECLARE @myTable TABLE (col1 INT, col2 DATETIME)`

Answer (score 3):

Try to google and read about "Dynamic SQL"

```
DECLARE @tbl_var as varchar(50)
SET @tbl_var = 'Table_Sales'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tbl_var

EXEC (@sql);
```

OR (better):

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```